# Is the question about the bug behind the draperies solidly or marginally on topic, or is it off topic?

Tags: discussion

I don't feel strongly about this [bug behind the draperies question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/27541/what-bug-is-this-behind-my-drapes)`, but I do think it is at best only marginally on topic.

The bugs are inside, and were found behind inside curtains in one of the most indoorsy of tasks: vacuuming. However, they might be outdoor bugs, and we have had a question about keeping outdoor critters (mice) outdoors.
See [this Question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13452/how-can-i-keep-outdoor-critters-outdoors).

The mice question asks about migration from the outdoors to the indoors, while the bug behind the draperies is purely an identification question. We have had a lot of ID questions, but this one just seems almost purely an indoors question.

Where do we draw the line?  Is anything that migrates from the outdoors to the indoors on topic?  What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally tend to be okay with such questions because we aren't SO or a similar programming Q&A.
However, I agree to the point that there should be a line drawn and anything on the other-side of it should be treated as a off-topic. That said, it is a fairly  complicated and unnecessary thing to achieve in the present state.

We have had question about bird/insects/bugs/snakes identification and not all of them have direct correlation with an outdoor adventure and/or recreational activity, and those are received quite well (and I hope will be so, looking at the kind of community we have here).
The point is - the moment we go into minute details such as whether this bug is found indoor or outdoors, we kill the fun/purpose there itself.
Because, OP should be able to receive whatever correct advice from TGO which would help him/her indoors as well outdoors as long as we aren't talking about fixing indoor board-games or discussing guns for protection from animals!
On a broader case, irrelevant to the example you have referred to, we have had well-received questions about storing an outdoor equipment. Going ahead, anyone can argue over whether storing stuff inside is on-topic or not - that is not where I would not want this community to go.
In general, this particular question would fit well at Biology.SE but no harm in we keeping it at TGO.

Thanks for bringing this up.